# Elif and else problems - Discord bot

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

So basically I have a discord bot, where you have to guess a number from {min} - {max} in order to win a price. Admins have permission to do a command -guess {min} {max}. Discord users guesses the number in channel, that command was executed. Almost everything works perfectly, except elif and else functions. They don't display any errors in console, the bot just ignores them. If they guess the number correctly, bot says ({msg.author} has guessed the number. The number was {choice}). I wanted to make, if they guess a number higher than {max}, It just displays (Number too big, try between {min} - {max}). There is my code. Can you tell me why my elif and else function just kept getting ignored?

```
@bot.command()
async def guess(ctx, min:int, max:int):
    if not ctx.author.id in bot.devs:
        return
    choice = random.randint(min, max)
    print(choice)
    await ctx.send(f'Choose a number between {min} - {max}')

    def check(m):
        return m.content == f"{choice}" and m.channel == ctx.channel
    msg = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
    if msg.content == f"{choice}":
        embed=discord.Embed(title=f"**Giveaway Winner**", description=f"{msg.author} has won the giveaway! The answer was {choice}")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    elif msg.content >= f"{max}":
        embed=discord.Embed(title=f"**Number is too big**", description=f"{msg.author} try between {min} - {max}")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"{msg.author}You guessed wrong. Try again")
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line `elif msg.content >= f"{max}":`,  you're comparing two strings with a mathematical operator,
instead try `elif int(msg.content) >= max:`

Comment: `elif int(msg.content) >= max:`